# Ошибка в запросе axios.get при изменении route vue 3

Tags: vue.js, get, axios, vue3, vue-router

Доброго времени суток товарищи, это мой первый вопрос, буду краток.
Вот в этом проекте у меня ошибка https://github.com/JohnnySench/my-morty-main
Суть в том, что при заходе в карточку персонажа, меняется route и в зависимости от route, должен делать запрос, для получения инфы этого перса. Прилагаю два скрина как я пытался решить проблему, но ничего не вышло, третье решение на самом репозитории.
Если кто знает, почему и как предложите свое решение, потому что я закончился.
[Как я пытался решить](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S463P.jpg)

[image: Сам actions с запросом]com/S463P.jpg

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.